# Term for people who cause accidents just to look like a hero

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the term for people who cause accidents so that they can step in, save the day and look like a hero?

Comment: You mean someone who intentionally creates dangerous situations in order to look like the hero of the moment?

Comment: Aye, that's probably more precise.

Comment: Sounds like Münchausen by proxy to me.

Comment: Attention seeker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They would be said to have "a [hero complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_complex)" or "hero syndrome".  [This New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/08/02/nyregion/experts-say-hero-syndrome-not-common-among-police.html?sec=health) claims there's little research into it, so that may explain the lack of nomenclature.

Answer (score 3):

It's Münchausen Hero syndrome. A person with this disorder will put another in a dangerous situation so that he/she can then "save" them.

(Münchausen by Proxy is generally used to refer to a parent or guardian who knowingly and willfully harms their child or another in their care in order to garner sympathy and attention.)

Comment: Münchhausen (two "h"s, by the way) specifically refers to a false illness.  Do you have any reference for this use or is this something you came up with on your own?

Comment: You'd be correct if we were talking about the Baron Münchhausen, but the disease (at least in most medical textbooks) is spelled with one H.

Comment: Ugh.  Looks like you're right.  Fie to coiners who can't spell!